# How to show all the associated posts with specific date of data metabox?

Tags: wp-query, metabox, post-meta, meta-query

I need someone to answer this question.
I have metabox which shows date:

```
 $date = rwmb_meta( 'pb_match_date', '', $post->ID );
```

I want to get all the associated posts with specific date of that metabox as follows:

**23 Oct 16:**

1. Post 1
2. Post 2

**27 Oct 16:**

1. Post 1
2. Post 2
3. Post 3

What will be the query?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post' )        
);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
    $dates = rwmb_meta( 'pb_match_date','', $post->ID);
    foreach ( $dates as $date ) { 
        //Is it correct? If not then what is the way?
    }
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: What does `rwmb_meta` do?

Comment: As same as :get_post_meta()

Comment: Are you only requesting a specific date?  Or are you attempting to list all posts and then organize them based on that `pb_match_date` field?

Comment: @socki03 No, [`rwmb_meta()`](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box/blob/5b09bd8098addda2c560273787f84e0fc2495107/inc/functions.php#L16-L35) is not the same. And in case you want to keep this open and on topic: Go with plain meta handling instead of _Rilwis Metabox_ plugin.

Comment: @kaiser Thanks for the info, hadn't seen that function before and was too lazy to learn about a plugin I didn't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the case correctly your $args should be something like that:

```
$args          = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 5, // what ever you like
                'paged'          => $page, // page number tracker
                'post_type'      => 'post', // or change to custom
                'post_status'    => array( 'draft', 'publish' ),
                'meta_query'     => array(
                     array(
                         'meta-key'     => 'pb_match_date',
                         'meta-compare' => 'EXISTS'
                      ),
                 ),
            );
```

This will return all posts where 'pb_match_date' exists, then you can extract the value and build upon.

You can always reference the codex for more details:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query